# Python csv module to read specific line

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

My current code prints the column that has integers, but some responses have appeared and i need them to be in column 6.

```
import csv

with open('WEATHER_1113.txt', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    with open('right_format.csv', 'w') as new_file:
        #csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)

    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line[5])
```

Comment: please add input and expected output.

Comment: Expected output would be all data in string format to be in column 6

Comment: I have numbers in column 5 and sentences in coumn 6. Some of the sentences appear in column 5 when need to be in column 6.

Comment: without simple data input ! we will be unable to detect the issue ! also you don't need to use `with open('right_format.csv', 'w') as new_file:`

Comment: Input data can be found here https://termbin.com/r9w3 notice how some of the responses have crept into the TimeToAudioRes column!

Comment: so you would like to print column# 5 if it's only integers?

Comment: I would like to re-write the whole data set making sure all values are in correct columns

Comment: your code working well. https://pasteboard.co/IGxPp0R.png

Comment: Its getting an utterance in the time column you see, that needs to be in "Responses" column.

Comment: just for confirm, it's about `It's currently a clear sky and 34 degrees fahrenheit.`?

Comment: Yes! That is a great example. This type of response needs to be in column 6!

Comment: `"what's the forecast","WeatherSkill","handle_current_weather","0.34","0.769","It's currently a clear sky and 34 degrees fahrenheit.","Today's forecast is for a high of 45 and a low of 33."` so here is `It's currently a clear sky and 34 degrees fahrenheit` in column 5 !

Comment: the issue is in your data actually ! if you take a look on your data ! you will see that the wrong data usually have 2 columns of float but the correct data have 3 columns !

Comment: is there A python script to fix that?

Comment: your correct data is `7` columns but your wrong data is `6` columns. so in case if you would like to fix that ! you will need to modify the data which contain 6 columns by inserting any value of your decision . etc in columns 4,5 or 6 ! something like inserting `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

with open('WEATHER_1113.txt', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for line in csv_reader:
        if line[5][1] == '.':
            print(line[5])
```

that's should give you the expected output since your data not matching together in number of columns !

Comment: To do this for all and write to new csv? examples before and after: https://pasteboard.co/IGyO7dZ.png                  https://pasteboard.co/IGyOQc5.png